# Android: Upload new APK, use previous APK Expansion File

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

Somebody please help me. I have an Android project and I want to upload a new APK to Play. I do not wish to change my expansion file, and I wish to use an older expansion file. My apk version code is 15, and I wish to use expansion version 14. Can somebody please provide some code to download version 14, because everytime I test my app version 15, it tries to download version 15 of apk expansion and it does not exist. I want version 14.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer myself, after trying like a thousand different setups. Here is how it works: Whenever you upload an apk you have a choice of either upload a new expansion or using an older one. Whenever you choose a new one, it renames it to match the version code of your apk, and when user downloads the app, they get apk version code matching expansion code. Whenever you choose an existing expansion, it does not rename the expansion. So when the user downloads the app, they get apk version code with an older expansion code. So, the only thing you must check in your C#/Java is when you are actually accessing your .obb, to make sure you are accessing the right code.